# Tensorflow cannot initialize tf.Variable for dynamic batch size

Tags: tensorflow

I tried creating a tf.Variable with a dynamic shape. The following outlines the problem.

Doing this works.

```
init_bias = tf.random_uniform(shape=[self.config.hidden_layer_size, tf.shape(self.question_inputs)[0]])
```

However, when i try to do this:

```
init_bias = tf.Variable(init_bias)
```

It throws the error ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("random_uniform:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32)

Just come context (question input is a placeholder which dynamic batch ):

```
self.question_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, self.config.qmax])
```

It seems like putting a dynamic value into random uniform gives shape=(?,?) which gives an error with tf.Variable.

Thanks and appreciate any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
init_bias = tf.Variable(init_bias,validate_shape=False)
```

If [validate_shape](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable.__init__) is False, tensorflow allows the variable to be initialized with a value of unknown shape.

However, what you're doing seems a little strange to me. In tensorflow, Variables are generally used to store weights of a neural net, whose shape remains fixed irrespective of the batch size. Variable batch size is handled by passing a variable length tensor into the graph (and multiplying/adding it with a fixed shape bias Variable).

Comment: I found an use case in preloading data: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#preloaded_data. You might want to feed different datasets of different sizes.

Comment: I still get an error `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype int32  [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[], device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
`